# setup.py adding relative paths inside python scripts

Tags: python

I have build the package for this structure

```
/mypackage
    setup.py
    /mypackage
        __init__.py
        file1.py
        file2.py
        /subpackage
            __init__.py
            file3.py
            myschema.schema
```

my setup.py looks like this:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name = 'MyPackage',
    description = 'This is my package',
    packages = ['mypackage', 'mypackage.subpackage'], 
    package_data={
        'mypackage': ['subpackage/*.schema']
    },
    version = '1',
    install_requires=[
    'jsonschema', 'pyyaml', 'requests', 'urllib3'
     ]
    url = 'http://www.myorg.org/',
    author = 'Me',
    author_email = 'me@helloworld.com',
)
```

when I run  `python3 setup.py sdist bdist_wheel` this creates distribution files along with egg_info in `version.tar.gz` files.
Please be aware that, nor in any my python files I used any kind of relative paths before calling the module.

e.g. in file1.py

```
from file2 import * --> no (.) next to file2
```

So, now in end-system i call this 
using `pip install -v --user -r requirements.txt --index-url "$(indexURL)"` 
PS: requirements.txt got version of tar.gz

but as soon as I tried to run file1.py , it says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file1.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .file2 import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named __main__.file2; __main__ is not a package
```

I think when
setup.py install runs for mypackage, it adds the relative path. May be I'm wrong but how can I fix this?